# Plotting only the positive $x$-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm not experient with tikz package. I'm trying to plot a function graph, but is compiling only the positive $x$-axis. Also, I tried to plot another graph of the missed part, but produces tha same image. I would like to know what causes this and how to fix it.

```
 \documentclass[tikz]{report}

 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage[all]{xy}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{amscd}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{mathabx}

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{times}
 \usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
 \usepackage{mdframed}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 
 \everymath{\displaystyle}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

 \begin{document}

 $$\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   domain=-3:3,
   xtick={-2,0,2},ytick={-3,0,3},
   y=0.4cm,x = 0.4cm, xmax=4,ymax=4,ymin=-4,xmin=-4,
   axis lines=middle,
   ]
 \addplot[domain=-3:3,blue,smooth]{\x^(2/3)*(\x^2-4)};
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}$$

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That seems normal: non-integer powers of x are defined only for x > 0, as the mathematical definition of x^a is `e^(a ln x)`. Maybe try  with the formula `(x^2)^{1/3}`.

Comment: @Bernard thank you! It worked!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.